# Error doing web.config transformation for different environments

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-config-transform

I was trying to deploy my app into different environments then i started following this how to:
[Deploying an ASP.NET Web Application to a Hosting Provider using Visual Studio or Visual Web Developer: Web.Config File Transformations - 3 of 12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-web-config-file-transformations-3-of-12)

was perfect until I clicked in **Preview Transform**, I received this error:

> **Microsoft Visual Studio**
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

(I created just one transformation **Web.DebugQA.config** and of course the default ones, debug and release)

my **Web.DebugQA.config** looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" 
      connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="EnvironmentName" value="QADev" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)"
      xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

but then I install this plugin:

[SlowCheetah - XML Transforms](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WillBuikMSFT.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms)

and I solved my preview transform error, but then when I was trying to publish using the QADev transform I got this error:

> The "ImportParametersFile" task failed unexpectedly.
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>      at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.ImportParametersFile.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value `[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]` (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value `[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]`.

I'm using Visual Studio Pro 2012.

Answer (score 32):

I fixed this by repairing "Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 - Visual Studio 2012" from Control Panel --> Programs and Features.

The file Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll was missing from the path C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web.

Comment: I encountered this same error, though I am not using an xml transform plugin like slow cheetah, so it may be for different reasons, but this solved my issue without adding in new errors/warnings

Comment: If you don't have VS2012 installed — because you're a build server or you have 2012 Express or you have 2010 and 2013 but nothing in between (my problem), this package won't be present and won't install from scratch.

Comment: Also confirmed that it works for me. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Yes It worked for me and run visual studio under Administrator rights.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error, although it was caused for different reasons.

I solved it copying the following DLL from another PC with VS2012 installed:
**Microsoft.Web.XmlTransforms.dll**

from:  **C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web**

I hope this helps

Comment: We don't have any PCs with VS2012 installed (we have 2010 and 2013). The 2013 version appears to be a different version and `PublicKeyToken`.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem in VS2012, could not 'Preview Transform' for the PublishPackage tranforms e.g. Web.Staging.config complaining about Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform

I got it working by adding the Package https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Xdt to my Mvc 4.5 project.  This package is still in pre release.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Xdt -Pre
```

This package contains the Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll

I still get an error during building complaining about "Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform".  The Mvc project has still built ok.

I did try adding the Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll to the Gac using the gacutil but that did not fix the problem.

However I use Team Foundation Service build server and it works and creates the correct Web.config after applying the Web.Release.config and then the Web.Staging.config.

Answer (score 1):

I tried below two things but it did not work for me.

1) copying the Microsoft.Web.XmlTransforms.dll DLL to location C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web

2) And repairing "Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 - Visual Studio 2012"

**Then I uninstalled Microsoft Azure tool V2.6 from control panel -> Programs and Features**. And then I can able to publish my site.

Answer (score 0):

This may have been fixed in Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 (and Visual Studio 2013).

> [Web.config "Preview Transform" gives an error](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/777749/web-config-preview-transform-gives-an-error)
>
> > ...
> >
> > Posted by Microsoft on 3/1/2013 at 2:46 PM
> >
> > Thanks for reporting the issue! It will be fixed in Visual Studio 2012 Update 2. Please install it when it becomes available.

Comment: That doesn't help if you don't have Visual Studio 2012 installed — either because you have VS Express installed or because you're on a build server.