# The "TransformXml" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

Our project was updated to use .net 4.5.1 from .net 4.0. After downloading and updating the .net 4.5.1 in my VS 2012,i am ending up with error below. can any one help to solve the issue

```
The "TransformXml" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.TransformXml.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Looks similar as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776659/error-doing-web-config-transformation-for-different-enviroments). Did you install update 2 of VS2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i got a fix.

Webtools 2013.1 package is the one that installs Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform  in our pc, and the dll should be located on "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web" folder.

just by copying and replacing the dll file from another pc vs2012 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have installed the Microsoft Web Tools for 4.5.1

Ensure the dll (with the appropriate version number) is located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web"